# VSIX IClassifier vs ITagger<IClassificationSpan>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I develop VSIX extension for Visual Studio (2015 and 2017) which adds custom syntax coloring to the code editor. For these I have found two different examples on MSDN: one used IClassifier and the other used ITagger<IClassificationSpan>.

What is the difference between them?

EDIT:
To be more precise, I need to add my own classification of the source code, for example, I want to add color to the specific words.

Comment: MSDN says _Tags are markers that are associated with a span of text. They can be presented in different ways, for example, by
using text coloring, underlines, graphics, or pop-ups. Classifiers are one kind of tag._ So for coloring use Classification for other purposes use Tagging.

Answer (score 1):

An `IClassifier`gets applied to the text behind the editor - and it recognizes words (simplified). Words found by an `IClassifier` are represented as so-called classification spans. The classifier is assigned with a format... plain text, for instance.

An `IClassifier` can be used by an `ITagger` to find the classification spans of certain types for further analysis... for instance, that could be spell checking, or as shown in the walkthrough, a tagger that finds TODO comments only. This walkthrough may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361745.aspx

Comment: Thanks, for reply) Still It doesn't answer my question. The given example reuses existing classifications while I need to add my own. Probably my question wasn't very precise so I edited it. Still it remains the same - what are the differences between IClassifier and ITagger<IClassificationSpan>.
Cause for example in the Roslyn Colorizer extension the ITagger approach is used:
https://github.com/tomasr/roslyn-colorizer/blob/master/RoslynColorizer/RoslynColorizer.cs